# Communication between React and Nextjs projects

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, vite

I have one problem. Now, I have a portfolio website and I want to add blog functionality to this website. I will create My Blog tab at my navbar. When I click the My Blog tab, I want to open my nextjs project. My original portfolio website is developed by me with react and vite. I don't want use microservice architecture because my hosting plan don't support this and I don't want create another website for my Blog. How can I achieve that scenario?

I tried monorepo, but it didn't work. I encountered a lot of errors. Even if I asked that problem to ChatGPT, it couldn't find the answer. ChatGPT told me:
To create a monorepo with React + Vite and Next.js using npm, you can follow these general steps:

1.Set up the monorepo directory:

Create a new directory for your monorepo project.
Open a terminal and navigate to the monorepo directory.

2.Initialize the monorepo:

Run npm init in the terminal to initialize the monorepo.
Follow the prompts to set up the package.json file for your monorepo.

3.Create project directories:

Inside the monorepo directory, create separate directories for your React + Vite portfolio project and your Next.js blog project.
For example, create directories named portfolio and blog inside the monorepo.

4.Initialize the projects:

Navigate to the portfolio directory in the terminal.
Run npm init to initialize the portfolio project.
Follow the prompts to set up the package.json file for the portfolio project.
Repeat the same steps for the blog directory to initialize the Next.js blog project.

5.Install dependencies:

Navigate to the monorepo root directory in the terminal.
Run npm install to install the dependencies for the monorepo.
This will create a node_modules directory in the monorepo root.

6.Configure project-specific dependencies:

Inside each project's directory (portfolio and blog), install the required dependencies for the respective projects.
For the React + Vite portfolio project, install the necessary dependencies using npm install.
For the Next.js blog project, install the required dependencies using npm install.

I followed this introductions but they didn't work. On the other hand I tried a lot of solutions but I try to find best.

Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.